# Using replaceChild to replace p element in form

Tags: javascript, forms, button

Hello I have a little problem and I really don't know how to fix it. So I have a form in the one I did put a button, and this button is in a p element. When you "click" the button I want to replace the p element with an other p element in the one I have some elements (type=text) and a button. But the browser says he can not replaceChild of null. why if i replace the form with my p element it works but I don't have anymore my form just the p stays and if i replace the form element.childNodes[1](http://codepen.io/danyweis/pen/zZpOBd?editors=1010) the browser directly reloads ?

This works but not like I want

```js
var contenu = document.getElementById("contenu");
var boiteElt = document.createElement("p");
var btnElt = document.createElement("p");
var formElt = document.createElement("form");
formElt.id = "leFrom";

var inputAuteur = document.createElement("input");
var inputValidation = document.createElement("button");
inputValidation.type = "submit";
inputValidation.textContent = "Ajouter";

var ajoutLien = document.createElement("button");
ajoutLien.id = "ajoutLien";
ajoutLien.textContent = "Ajouter un lien";
ajoutLien.addEventListener("click", function() {
    boiteElt.appendChild(inputAuteur);
    boiteElt.appendChild(inputValidation);

   contenu.replaceChild(boiteElt, contenu.childNodes[1]);

   //  this not works  ====>formElt.replaceChild(boiteElt, formElt.childNodes[1]);

});

inputValidation.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
 contenu.replaceChild(btnElt, contenu.childNodes[1]);
});
btnElt.appendChild(ajoutLien);
formElt.appendChild(btnElt);
contenu.appendChild(formElt);
```

```html
    <div id="contenu">
    </div>
```

**This does not work but I want something like this**

```
formElt.replaceChild(boiteElt, formElt.childNodes[1]);
```

I want to replace the p element not just the button

Thanks for your help and explications 
["my Codepen"](http://codepen.io/danyweis/pen/zZpOBd?editors=1010)

Comment: Do you mean `contenu.replaceChild(btnElt, contenu.childNodes[1]);`? The default action of `form` submission is not prevented.

Comment: that is what works. me i want to change the inside of the form

Answer (score 0):

Using buttons or inputs in [`<p>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) isn't allowed, because

- The content model of [`<button>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) element is [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) (with no [interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendant).
- And the [`<p>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) can only be used where [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1:) is expected.

An alternative is getting rid of the `p` element, and instead using a `<span>` element with `display: block` or `<div>` element